# Linq C# Group by Sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the below sample code that doesn't return the correct sum because it first calculates the sum, then it does the group by!

How do I first **group by**, then calculate the **sum**?

```
var result = (from orderItem in _orderItemRepository.Table
            join o in _orderRepository.Table on orderItem.OrderId equals o.Id
            join p in _productRepository.Table on orderItem.ProductId equals p.Id
            join psch in _productScheduleRepository.Table on p.Id equals psch.ProductId
            join sm in _storeMappingRepository.Table on new { c1 = p.Id, c2 = "Product" } equals new { c1 = sm.EntityId, c2 = sm.EntityName } into p_sm
            from sm in p_sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ...                        

            group new { orderItem, o,p } by new { orderItem.Id } into g


              select new
              {
                  TotalPriceExclTax = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceExclTax),
                  TotalPriceExclTaxStore = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceExclTax * x.p.PPStoreManagers),
                  TotalPriceExclTaxAdmin = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceExclTax * x.p.PPAdministrators),
                  TotalPriceInclTax = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceInclTax) 
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

```
group new { orderItem, o,p } by new { orderItem.Id } into g
```

[image: example]

Below is the dumped linq query for better explaination:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy2].[A2] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy2].[A3] AS [C3], 
    [GroupBy2].[A4] AS [C4], 
    [GroupBy2].[K1] AS [Id]
     FROM ( SELECT 
        [Filter4].[K1] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Filter4].[A1]) AS [A1], 
        SUM([Filter4].[A2]) AS [A2], 
        SUM([Filter4].[A3]) AS [A3], 
        SUM([Filter4].[A4]) AS [A4]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Filter1].[Id1] AS [K1], 
            [Filter1].[PriceExclTax] AS [A1], 
            [Filter1].[PriceExclTax] * [Filter1].[PPStoreManagers] AS [A2], 
            [Filter1].[PriceExclTax] * [Filter1].[PPAdministrators] AS [A3], 
            [Filter1].[PriceInclTax] AS [A4]
            FROM   (SELECT ...
                FROM     [dbo].[OrderItem] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product_Schedule_Mapping] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[ProductId]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[StoreMapping] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent3].[Id] = [Extent5].[EntityId]) AND (N''Product'' = [Extent5].[EntityName])
                WHERE [Extent2].[Deleted] <> cast(1 as bit) ) AS [Filter1]
            CROSS JOIN  (SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [A1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                    WHERE 1 = 0
                )  AS [GroupBy1]
                WHERE 0 = [GroupBy1].[A1] ) AS [Filter3]
            WHERE (...)
        )  AS [Filter4]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy2]
```

Comment: The two rows with ID of 3 look the same. Is that always going to be the case for all IDs? The semantics of the Linq query you used will sum all those duplicates, if that is what they are. Did you actually want `distinct` instead of `group by`?

Comment: i'm needing sum total orderItem.PriceExclTax by grouping after join tables in linq query

Comment: What are you using? `Linq-to-SQL` or `Linq-to-Entities`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Don't talk in `group by` etc... Are you trying to get the `TotalPrice`s of each `Order`?

Comment: i'm trying to get TotalPriceExclTax = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceExclTax),TotalPriceExclTaxStore = g.Sum(x => x.orderItem.PriceExclTax * x.p.PPStoreManagers),... of each store's orderitems

Comment: i'm using linq-to-entities by autofac(ioc= Inversion of Control)

Comment: You're using **Inner Join** on each table, but it sounds like you need to use **Lerft** | **Right** join instead. What is entity model?